# File Handling Problem,while opening a file in a read mode

Tags: c++, data-structures, file-handling

I have an assignment to take an input from the user and wrote it in file and successfully wrote the file like the function given below,and it is working nicely

```cpp
void add_category(string NAME, int ID_category)
{
    category* newnode;
    newnode = new category;
    newnode->name_of_category = NAME;
    newnode->id = ID_category;
    if (headd == NULL) {
        headd = newnode;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        newnode->pre = NULL;
        lastd = newnode;
    }
    else {
        lastd->next = newnode;
        newnode->pre = lastd;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        lastd = newnode;
    }
    dlength++;

    ofstream file("Category.txt", ios::app);
    category* temp = headd;
    category* temp2;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        file << temp->name_of_category << endl;
        file << temp->id << endl;
        temp2 = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        delete temp2;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

But the problem is that while opening a file by code get crashed or TBH I don't how I can open a file. I am using double linked list. My task is to open a file in a read mode and delete the category entered by the user. Here is my function of deleting the category:

```cpp
void delete_category(string remove_name)
{
    category* currentptr = headd;
    category* temp;
    category* temp2;
    category* temp3 = headd;

    ifstream file("Category.txt");

    if (!file) {
        cout << "file can not open" << endl;
    }
    else {
        while (temp3 != NULL && !file.eof()) {
            file >> temp3->name_of_category;
            file >> temp3->id;
            temp3 = temp3->next;
        }
    }

    int save = search_category(remove_name);

    cout << save << endl;

    if (dlength <= 0) {
        cout << " NO category found" << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (save == 0) {
            temp = headd;
            headd = headd->next;
            headd->pre = NULL;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 1; i < save; i++) {
                currentptr = currentptr->next;
            }

            temp = currentptr->next;
            temp2 = temp->next;

            currentptr->next = temp2;
            temp2->pre = currentptr;
        }

        dlength--;

        delete temp;

        cout << " Successfully Deleted the Category" << endl;
    }
}
```

As I have called the searched function in the deleting category, I have used the same method for opening a file in search function:

```cpp
int search_category(string search)
{
    category* currentptr = headd;
    int flag = 0;
    category* temp3 = headd;

    ifstream file("Category.txt");

    if (!file) {
        cout << "file can not open" << endl;
    }
    else {
        while (temp3 != NULL && !file.eof()) {

            file >> temp3->name_of_category;
            file >> temp3->id;

            temp3 = temp3->next;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dlength; i++) {
        if (currentptr->name_of_category == search) {
            flag = 1;
            return i;
        }

        currentptr = currentptr->next;
    }

    if (flag == 0) {
        cout << " Sorry not found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Please correct me where I am making a mistake to open a file.

Comment: You will want to review [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading data many times from the same file, just read it once into memory and work on it.

```
using Category = std::pair<int, std::string>;
std::vector<Category> categories;

{
  Category cat;
  std:ifstream file("Category.txt");

  while (file >> cat.first >> cat.second)
    categories.push_back(cat);
}

auto novels = std::find_if(std::begin(categories), std::end(categories),
    [](const Category &category) { return category.second == "novels"; });
```

Comment: You are right but i cannot use the vector,in my assignment

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem is the usage of `ios::app` mode. Refer to [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/).
`app` mode is used for appending not writing, so what happened is that the file indicator is positioned at the end of the file.
I hope this helps you solve your problem.